# get value out of the key/value pair

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, boto, boto3

This might be really trivial question for some python pros out there, but i am using boto3 to get some snapshot information....i do the below and get a the out.... my question is how do i get just the "VolumeId", i thought as this is a key value output i can use something value rs.value to get that but i do not get desired output...

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('ec2')
>>> rs = client.describe_snapshots(SnapshotIds=['snap-656f5566'])
>>> print rs
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '6f99cc31-f586-48cf-b9bd-f5ca48a536fe'}, u'Snapshots': [{u'Description': 'Created by CreateImage(i-bbe81dc1) for ami-28ne0f44 from vol-72e14126', u'Encrypted': False, u'VolumeId': 'vol-41e14536', u'State': 'completed', u'VolumeSize': 30, u'Progress': '100%', u'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 7, 14, 33, 16, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'SnapshotId': 'snap-658f5566', u'OwnerId': '0111233286342'}]}
>>>
>>>
>>> dir(rs)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values']
>>>
>>> print rs.keys
<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x1e76a60>
>>>
>>> print rs.values
<built-in method values of dict object at 0x1e76a60>
>>>
```

Error after fixing

```
>>> print rs.keys()
['ResponseMetadata', u'Snapshots']
>>> print(rs['ResponseMetadata']['Snapshots'][0]['VolumeId'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Snapshots'
>>>
```

Comment: @CasualDemon...thank you but i get above error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are functions, call them like:

```
print rs.keys()
print rs.values()
```

To get that exact metadata:

```
print(rs['Snapshots'][0]['VolumeId'])
```

Edit:

As @Anand S Kumar points out, if there are more than a single snapshot you will have to iterate over them in a loop as he demonstrated.

Comment: I think i need to do something like "print(rs['Snapshots'][0]['VolumeId'])" to get the volumeid ?

Comment: You are correct, I missread the dictionary, thinking "Snapshots" was inside "ResponseMetadata".

Answer (score 3):

`rs.values` is a function, you need to call it -

```
print rs.values()
```

Same for `rs.keys` , its also a function, call it - `rs.keys()` .

But if your case to just get the `VolumeId` , you can directly access it using `subscript` after first getting the list of snapshots and then iterating over it and getting `volumeId` for each snapshot -

```
snapshots = rs['Snapshots']
for snapshot in snapshots:
    print snapshot['VolumeId']
```

Or as @CasualDemon has given in his answer, if you only want the `VolumeId` for the first Snapshot, you can do -

```
print rs['Snapshots'][0]['VolumeId']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken what you want to get is the value(s) associated with u'VolumeId',
that is 'vol-41e14536' (and more values if you had several snapshots).

rs is a dictionary whose u'Snapshot' key is associated with a list of dictionary (actually of only one dictionary), and these dictionary contain a key u'VolumeId' whose associated value you want.

```
{ ....                   u'Snapshot' : [                                 {...                        u'VolumeId': 'vol-41e14536' ...}  ] ... }
^Beginning of dictionary ^key          ^Value(list of dictionaries)      ^firstElement(a dictionary) ^The key you are looking for and its value
```

What you could do is

```py
snapshots = rs[u'Snapshots']
volumeIds = []
for snapshotDict in snapshots :
    volumeIds.append(snapshotDict[u'VolumeId'])
print(volumeIds)
```

Assuming python3 syntaxe